# The autoload in Symfony

Tags: symfony, composer-php, autoload, spl-autoload-register

In vendor/composer/autoload_real.php in symfony project the function getLoader is called from autoload.php

In this function, I have :

```
spl_autoload_register(array('ComposerAutoloaderInit374429f4ab4935127e2d36a0613c8d3a', 'loadClassLoader'), true, true);
```

The spl_autoload_register register two autoloader "**ComposerAutoloaderInit374429f4ab4935127e2d36a0613c8d3a**" and "**loadClassLoader**"

The function "**loadClassLoader**" exist but I cann't found the "**ComposerAutoloaderInit374429f4ab4935127e2d36a0613c8d3a**" function.

My question is :

> There is "ComposerAutoloaderInit374429f4ab4935127e2d36a0613c8d3a" a
>   autoloader function or the nameclass?

If it is an autoloder function, where is in the class?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is actually only one autoloader, the array is a callback.

`ComposerAutoloaderInit374429f4ab4935127e2d36a0613c8d3a` is a name of the class, `loadClassLoader` is the name of its method to be used.

The class is defined directly in `autoload_real.php` file, the method is the first method in the class.

Comment: Thanks Finwe, That is what I need. So the first item in the array passed in the first argument to the spl_autoload_register is the name of the class